# Problem with displaying data?

Tags: visualforce, profile, userlicense, ui, custom-profile

I have created a custom profile from sys admin profile and assigned it to a user with salesforce license. Now, this user is unable view the data from a particular VF page. What could be possible mistake i have done?

Comment: Check your controller classes if you have any conditions to allow specific profiles to see data in your VF pages.

Comment: No i haven't made any profile based conditions.

Comment: Does it mean some fields of a record or complete records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your custom profile.

Below **Enabled Visualforce Page Access** edit and add your page.

You need to give object level access as well.

After discussion with @Venky. Found issue. Issue with object level access. Need to check view all data checkbox.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, I have added required vf pages, classes, provided access to the objects & fields.

Comment: @Venky  goto your object --> field--> click on security sharing button --> check the fields are editable to that profile or not?

Comment: Yes they have edit access.

Comment: could there be any problem due to customized jquery plugin, just a doubt!

Comment: Just now i have gone through debug logs & found that page has complete access to the data from apex class & the only problem is with showing the data.

Comment: How to check the logs for data from jquery as we write it on page itself?